# text wrapping around an image across several A4 sheets

Tags: pdf

I am doing a project that intends to cover a wall with the words of a book. It will consist of 84 sheets of A4 paper, (cut to remove the margin), with six columns on each sheet. The text is printed in a 5pt font. The sheets are arranged 14 across and 6 down.

If that were all it would be easy and I would do it in LibreOffice. However, I have a large "white" image that I need to superimpose on the sheets. The image is formed by the words wrapping round the invisible image.

I thought Latex might help, but cannot see how it can work across multiple sheets of paper in a matrix layout. Is there a free software package that could handle this, or will I have to resort to writing some code? ( I've 30 years C experience, and interested in learning python. )

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Is clipping a possibility? As in you just overlay a tiled image over each page with no regard for the text (some show and some are hidden behind the image)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I solved the problem within LibreOffice Writer. I created a large page layout ( 3m x 2m ) and created 84 columns on it. I then deposited my text onto it, all 500,000 words, in 2 point font size. I then placed my image on the sheet, and used wrapping with contour enabled to wrap the text around the image. Finally, I exported the  document to pdf and used the poster feature in the print option to get my 42 sheets of A3 out. Long winded, but got me there. If someone would like to suggest how this could be done better in Tex I'd like to hear it.